# removing greater-than-sign symbol from string?

Tags: php

i have text like this :

```
<p>Mix together the mustard, honey, lemon zest and juice, remaining olive oil and season.> Pour over the quinoa and mix together.Add the toasted pumpkin seeds, basil leaves, chopped avocado, peas and scatter over rocket. Mix gently and serve immediately.</p>
>
<p>Cook the peas for 2 minutes in boiling water, refresh under cold running water and drain.</p>
>
```

My text also have p tags , so i can't use str_replace .So is there anyway to remove this  ">" symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution-

```
$str = "<p>Mix together the mustard, honey, lemon zest and juice, remaining olive oil and season.> Pour over the quinoa and mix together.Add the toasted pumpkin seeds, basil leaves, chopped avocado, peas and scatter over rocket. Mix gently and serve immediately.</p>
>
<p>Cook the peas for 2 minutes in boiling water, refresh under cold running water and drain.</p>
>";

echo $str;
$str= str_replace('>', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('<p', '<p>', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: that's so simple , silly am I :( . Thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use `preg_replace()` function

```
$str= preg_replace('/^\>/m', '', $str);
```

It will remove `>` at the begining of line.

Comment: but question is to remove `>` not `<`

Comment: but my ">"  don't begining of line ? :(

Comment: <p>Cook the peas for 2 minutes in boiling water, refresh under cold running water and drain.</p>
                                  
                                      >

it look like this

Comment: so remove `^` I think I don't understand now what exactly you want to do

Comment: i don't know how to import image to this page . So you can go to this image 
imgur.com/mutl8bW

Comment: Thank for your help . I think i will use @Hirdesh Vishwdewa code :D

Answer (score 3):

For hours, I was thinking why I couldn't remove greater and smaller strings, it should be easy then I released that, html entity codes are different.

```
$string= str_replace('&gt;', '', $string);
$string= str_replace('&lt;', '', $string);



&gt;     : > (greater-than)
&lt;     : < (less-than)
&amp;    : & (ampersand)
&raquo;  : » (right angle quote marks)
&eacute; : é (e acute)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple option would be to use Trim and pass the symbols as the second argument (The charlist) like so:

```
trim($string, " <>");
```

Simple but effective!